# Can I use "Verb + Infinitive + Gerund"?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, gerunds, infinitives

Can verb, infinitive, and gerund be used together? Especially in this sentence:

> That book has helped me to overcome my struggling.

Helped + To overcome + Struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct. You could also omit *to* and the sentence would still be correct too:

***That book has helped me overcome my struggling.***

The version without *to* sounds better to me.